# How to extract published-time and article-content from a news article using java?

Tags: java, html

I have to extract published-time and article content from a news link.

ex: From this link
http://techcrunch.com/2013/03/19/jawbone-android/

I have to extract published-time and article content as

published-time: posted yesterday

article content:
Jawbone announced today that its app for UP, the company’s movement-tracking wristband, is now available as a free download for Android on Google Play. The $129 UP was previously only compatible with iOS. The wristband can also now be purchased......

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Comment: i did not get solution for that,someone suggested me  jsoup but it not suitable to my requirement.

Comment: @BoltClock The original questions has been removed and this one is closed because it's a duplicate. Is there a special reason why the original question has been removed ?

Comment: @mmx73: Probably because it was abandoned. Guess I'll reopen this one, then.

Comment: @rajumuddana did you get the solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use jsoup

http://jsoup.org/

jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

Comment: thanks CBroe.... i think jsoup is not suitable to my requirement,b'coz i don't know the tag name or position of published-time b'coz the tags are vary from one site to another.

Answer (score 0):

For article-text extraction you can use [BoilerPipe](http://github.com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe)

```
 ArticleExtractor extractor = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE
 String articleText = extractor.getText(yourHTML);
```